# Encoding Greek in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, encoding

I am trying to get encoding to Greek on on windows phone 8:

```
Encoding aaa = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-7");
```

The exception i get is 
'ISO-8859-7' is not a supported encoding name.
I also tried:

```
Encoding aaa = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1253");
Encoding aaa = Encoding.GetEncoding("1253");
Encoding aaa = Encoding.GetEncoding("el-GR");
```

I am testing it only at a emulator that has regional settings to Greece.
Currently i don't have a device to test it.

Comment: Why not Unicode? UTF-8?

Comment: According to the API lookup for WP8, you're limited to UTF-8 or Unicode.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/t9a3kf7c(v=vs.105).aspx